# present perfect vs past perfect vs simple past

Tags: tense, past-tense, perfect-constructions

> 1. The dancers **have rehearsed** the ballet for almost three hours.
> 2. They **have displayed** new CDs since Friday morning.
> 3. She **hasn't talked** to her brother since he broke her cell phone.

At first glance they seem to be fine, for example, *"The dancers **have** rehearsed the ballet for almost three hours",* seems to imply that they started 3 hours ago and they are still rehearsing. But something tells me that it should be, *"The dancers **had** rehearsed the ballet for almost three hours",* which also sounds correct, implying that they started some time ago, they rehearsed for 3 hours, but they have stopped since then. The other sentences have a similar structure.

**QUESTION:** Taking sentence #1 as an example,

> 4. The dancers **have rehearsed** the ballet for almost three hours.
> 5. The dancers **had rehearsed** the ballet for almost three hours.

without any other context, taking them (#4, #5) as standalone sentences, are both of them grammatically correct? If not, which one is correct and why?

Comment: As standalone sentences, both of them sound okay to me. :)

Answer (score 2):

> The dancers have rehearsed the ballet for almost three hours.

This is correct.

> The dancers had rehearsed the ballet for almost three hours **when I saw them**.

You don't use **the past perfect** tense alone in a sentence. 
You use it with the simple past to indicate two or more different points in time in the past.