# Has seen? Had seen? Had saw? Has saw?

Tags: grammar, tense, verbs

Could someone explain (in simple terms) which of the following are correct, and if they are correct, when to use them? Thanks.

> - has seen
> - had seen
> - had saw
> - has saw

Is this just a memorization thing? Thanks.

Comment: The last two only make sense in a kind of colloquial phrasing where *saw* is meant as the noun (the tool you use to *saw* things, such as pieces of wood). Just like we have the meme *Got milk?*, *had saw* and *has saw* could be used figuratively. *Wow, that guy really has saw! Look at how quickly he built that house!* (It would be unusual, but not incomprehensible.) But if you are using the verb form of *saw*, then the last two sentences are ungrammatical.

Comment: It's not just a memorization thing, it's a context thing. The first two can be "correct," but they don't mean the same thing, so they are only correct if they correctly convey what you are trying to say. I can say, "Donuts are the healthiest food in the world," and there is nothing grammatically wrong with that syntax, but it's hardly a correct statement.

Comment: So considering only the first two (has seen, and had seen), what is the difference? (Thanks for the help!)

Comment: These are the present perfect tense and past perfect tense. [Start Here.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46380/present-perfect-vs-past-perfect-vs-simple-past).  And [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/222251/37173). Plenty of reading is available here on ELL on “past perfect and present perfect.” Good luck!

Comment: So if I understand correctly: the person has seen the dog. The person saw the dog a while ago, and still sees it. The person had seen the dog. The person saw the dog, but now cannot see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Has seen* means that the event (seeing) started and ended at least once *before now*. This statement compares the past to the present. The event happened at Time A, it is now Time B and we are talking about the present (Time B).

*Had seen* means that the event (seeing) started and ended in the past at least once *before a second, more recent, time or event in the past* that has now ended. This statement compares the past to the past. The event happened at Time A and ended before Time B. It is now Time C and we are talking about Time B.

Example: Jerry saw the dog once per day on Monday, Tuesday, and Wednesday. On Wednesday, the dog chased him. If it is now Friday, we can say that

- Jerry *had* seen the dog twice before it chased him on Wednesday.
- Jerry *has* seen the dog three times (He saw it on Monday, Tuesday, and Wednesday).

*Had saw* and *has saw* are both incorrect. This is not just a memorization thing. Whether the event happened in the past relative to another in the past or relative to the present time determines which form to use.

Comment: Thanks. Makes more sense now.